# Dragging objects with mouse with glutWireCube()

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm working with OpenGL and I want to drag a cube with glutmotionfunc. I didn't finish at all, I don't know how to configure my views and I don't know what's wrong.

```
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glut.h>


    double rotate_y=0;
    double rotate_x=0;
    double rotate_z=0;

    GLfloat X = 0.0f;
    GLfloat Y = 0.0f;
    GLfloat Z = 0.0f;
    GLfloat scale = 1.0f;


    float ancho=800;
    float alto=600;
    int perspectiva = 0;
    float rx, ry;

    void motion(int x, int y)  // this is my motion function 
    // called when a mouse is in motion with a button down
    {
       printf("YYYMotion call back: %d, %d)\n", x, y);
       rx = x; 
       ry = alto - y;
     }

     void display()
     {
      //  Borrar pantalla y Z-buffer
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      // Resetear transformaciones
      glLoadIdentity();


       gluLookAt(1.0, 2.0, 50.0, //eye (x,y,z)
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0,           //at(x,y,z)
       0.0, 1.0, 0.0);          //up (x,y,z)
      glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
      glTranslatef((rx/ancho), (1-(ry/alto)), 0);

      glFlush();
      glutSwapBuffers();

     }
     void menu(int valor)
     {
       switch(valor)
       {
        case 1:
           glutWireTorus(0.5,2.0,20,20);
           break;
        case 2:
           glutWireTeapot(1.0);
           break;
        case 3:
           glutWireSphere(0.8,50,50);
           break;
        case 4:
           glutWireCube(1.0f);
           break;
        case 5:
           glutWireIcosahedron();
           break;
        case 6:
           glutWireOctahedron();
           break;
        case 7:
           glutWireTetrahedron();
           break;
        case 8:
           glutWireCone(0.5,1,5,5);
           break;
        case 9:
           exit(1);
           break;

    }
}
  void menu_opciones(void)
{
    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Torus",1);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Tetera",2);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Esfera",3);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Cubo",4);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Icosaedro",5);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Octaedro",6);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Tetraedro",7);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Cono",8);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Salir",9);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    // Habilitar la prueba de profundidad de Z-buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    ancho = 800;
    alto = 600;
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    menu_opciones();
    glLoadIdentity();


     //gluPerspective(80.0f, (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, 0.2f, 30.0f);

     //glOrtho(-2,2, -2, 2, 1, 10);
     //glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -2, 2);
    glFrustum (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 2.5, 50.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


}







int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    //  Inicializar los parámetros GLUT y de usuario proceso
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    // Solicitar ventana con color real y doble buffer con Z-buffer
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize (800, 600);
    glutInitWindowSize(ancho, alto);
    // Crear ventana
    glutCreateWindow("");
    init();
    // Funciones de retrollamada
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMotionFunc( motion);  
    //glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    //glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);

    // Pasar el control de eventos a GLUT
    glutMainLoop();

    // Regresar al sistema operativo
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you actually draw things? Something is missing:

```
void display()
 {
  //  Borrar pantalla y Z-buffer
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Resetear transformaciones
  glLoadIdentity();


   gluLookAt(1.0, 2.0, 50.0, //eye (x,y,z)
   0.0, 0.0, 0.0,           //at(x,y,z)
   0.0, 1.0, 0.0);          //up (x,y,z)
  glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
  glTranslatef((rx/ancho), (1-(ry/alto)), 0);

/* where are things actually drawn? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

 }
```

OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene graph. When you call OpenGL drawing functions, all it does is drawing points, lines or triangles to a framebuffer. One at a time each on its own. There is no such thing as "adding a model to a scene" in OpenGL. Son in your drawing code you actually have to draw something, to see something. And if something changes in your scene you have to redraw (everything).